# Python List IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list

I try to search in an list the maximal frequency of an element.

Now I have the problem that the last checked element of the list (a[i+1]) I get an IndexError. How can I solve this problem?

With len(a)-1 the last element a[i+1] is never used thus the result of maxMode(a4) is wrong.

```
a1 = [5,3,6,7,2,7,3,6,2,8,7]
a2 = [5,3,6,7,2,7,3,6,2,8,7,5,2]
a3 = [5,3,6,7,2,7,3,6,2,8,2,5,2]
a4 = [5,3,6,7,2,7,3,6,2,7,2,5,1]

def maxMode(a):
  cnt = 1
  maxCnt = 0
  res = 0
  for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[i] == a[i+1]:
      cnt += 1
    else:
      if cnt >= maxCnt:
        maxCnt = cnt
        res = a[i]
      cnt = 1
  return res

a1.sort()
a2.sort()
a3.sort()
a4.sort()

print(a1)
print(maxMode(a1))
print(a2)
print(maxMode(a2))
print(a3)
print(maxMode(a3))
print(a4)
print(maxMode(a4))
```

Comment: You are not working with arrays,  but with lists. Please fix the title.

Comment: It wont fix your code and just for your information: There is a method `a1.count(x)`, where `x` is your element, to count the occurence of an element.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BluCode points out, your code runs fine for the 4 test cases you provide (or at least, it doesn't crash and returns a mode although as you point out, for the 4th test, it's not the max mode).  Also, as you alluded to, you're not counting your last element (or really, you're not checking if the last batch could be the maximal), and so if a4 was instead: [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7], it wrongly prints out 2 (because it finds 3 2's and 3 7's and doesn't do a final check for the 7s being as good or better)

The following worked with my 4 updated test cases:

```
a1 = [5,3,6,7,2,7,3,6,2,8,7]
a2 = [5,3,6,7,2,7,3,6,2,8,7,5,2]
a3 = [5,3,6,7,2,7,3,6,2,8,2,5,2]
a4 = [5,3,6,7,2,7,3,6,2,7,2,5,1,7]

def maxMode(a):
  cnt = 1
  maxCnt = 0
  res = 0
  for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[i] == a[i+1]:
      cnt += 1
    else:
      if cnt >= maxCnt:
        maxCnt = cnt
        res = a[i]
      cnt = 1
  if cnt >= maxCnt:
    maxCnt = cnt
    res = a[i]
  return res

a1.sort()
a2.sort()
a3.sort()
a4.sort()

print(a1)
print(maxMode(a1))
print(a2)
print(maxMode(a2))
print(a3)
print(maxMode(a3))
print(a4)
print(maxMode(a4))
```